# Amazon Linux 2 worker fails to reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs, amazon-linux-2

I'm running a Node.js application on an Amazon Linux 2 worker instance, connected to SQS.

### The problem

It all runs fine, except that for technical reasons I need to restart the server regularly. To do this, I've set up a cron to run `/sbin/shutdown -r now` at night.

As the instance boots back up, I get an error regarding the SQS daemon service:

```
[INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
[INFO] get sqsd conf from cfn metadata and write into sqsd conf file ...
[INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf sqsd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active sqsd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start sqsd.service
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [startSqsd]. 
Stop running the command. Error: startProcess Failure: starting process "sqsd" failed: 
Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start sqsd.service failed with error exit status 1. 
Stderr:Job for sqsd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status sqsd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The instance is then stuck in a loop where the initialization runs until it hits the sqsd.service error and then starts over again.

### Logs

The `systemctl status sqsd.service` command doesn't appear to show much more information than we already got, only that it exited with status 1:

```
● sqsd.service - This is sqsd daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sqsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) (Result: exit-code)
  Process: 2748 ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c  (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2745 ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c rm -f /var/pids/sqsd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2753 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sqsd.service
           └─2789 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd start
```

The most interesting found when checking `journalctl -xe` is:

```
sqsd[9704]: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/bin/aws-sqsd:58:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid (Errno::ENOENT)
sqsd[9704]: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/bin/aws-sqsd:58:in `open'
sqsd[9704]: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/bin/aws-sqsd:58:in `start'
sqsd[9704]: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/bin/aws-sqsd:83:in `launch'
sqsd[9704]: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.3/bin/aws-sqsd:111:in `<top (required)>'
sqsd[9704]: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `load'
sqsd[9704]: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `<main>'
systemd[1]: sqsd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start This is sqsd daemon.
```

### Further investigation

As per the logs, the file `/var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid` does not exist when rebooting the server. It does exist on a rebuild and contains the application process ID.

If I add the file, the setup process gets a little bit further until a similar file is missing.

### Solutions?

Has anyone run into this issue before? Not sure why starting sqsd.service fails after a normal reboot but works fine on initial deploy and after rebuilding the environment... It almost seems like it's looking for a config file that doesn't exist...

Are there any other ways to safely reboot the instance that I should try?

Comment: I ran into this today after a reboot and the only thing that fixed it was terminating the instance (and letting Beanstalk spin up a replacement automatically). It didn't feel like it took any longer than a reboot would have. Not posting as an answer as rebooting/terminating is not a long-term solution imo.

Comment: For me it was terminating the instance and letting autoscale create a new one

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue. Not posting a solution but some more data on the issue. I found errors in /var/log/messages that suggest that the SQSd daemon ran out of memory.

```
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 sqsd: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:42:in `fork': Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 sqsd: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:42:in `start'
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 sqsd: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:83:in `launch'
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 sqsd: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/bin/aws-sqsd:111:in `<top (required)>'
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 sqsd: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `load'
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 sqsd: from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `<main>'
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 systemd: sqsd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 systemd: Failed to start This is sqsd daemon.
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 systemd: Unit sqsd.service entered failed state.
Apr 28 15:43:05 ip-172-31-121-3 systemd: sqsd.service failed.
```

After setting up a larger instance class, it was going through fine but I'm not sure that it wasn't just the refreshed instance that did it (like david.emilsson mentioned) or the extra memory.

Comment: Also, if you don't need the SQSd but you need a worker, just spin up a regular web server instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for ami linux 2:
File /etc/tmpfiles.d/aws-sqsd.conf should be added with next content:

> d /var/run/aws-sqsd 0755 root root
> f /var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid 0644 sqsd sqsd -

It will create directory /var/run/aws-sqsd and file /var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid

I added this config from application side using eb extensions

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on Elastic Beanstalk, due to a permissions issue (this wasn't clear due to a bug in older versions of systemd that Amazon Linux uses). Whilst not the most ideal solution, as I only had one instance rebuilding the environment solved my problem. Otherwise, follow Jeka's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look, I'm sure the answers above are valid, but I also ran into this problem but it was all my fault due to a typo in my cron.yaml.

Once I downloaded all the logs from the EB instance, I checked in the `aws-sqsd/default.log` file and saw this at the top:

```
2023-12-01T03:06:51Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.4 (2022-03-18)
2023-12-01T03:06:51Z init: Failed of parsing file 'cron.yaml', because: Bad Vixie-style specification /2 (AWS::EB::SQSD::ScheduleParser::ScheduleFileError)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.4/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:99:in `rescue in v1_parser'
```

I had a typo in one of my expressions in the `cron.yaml` file (in my case I wanted every two hours and had `schedule: "15 /2 * * *"` instead of `schedule: "15 */2 * * *"`)